# RXJS - Wait until store is not empty

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have a function like this:

```
combineLatest([this.contact$, this.account$]).pipe(
  map((res) => {contacts = res[0], account = res[1]})).subscribe()
```

but I need to find a solution because contact$ selector sometimes is empty and if is empty I need to invoke a service and populate the store. I tried in this way but obviously it doesn't work. This is an example of what I desire:

```
combineLatest([this.contact$, this.account$]).pipe(
  map((res) => {
    if(res[0].length === 0) {
      this.getContacts()
    }
    contacts = res[0];
    account = res[1]}
  ).subscribe()


getContacts() {
  this.myService.getContacts().subscribe(res => {
     this.store.dispatch(myAction.addContacts({contacts: res}))
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nice question, to which i have not found a solution without 'bad smell'.
Anyway, a working approach is:

- subscribe to your observable
- have a timeout (50ms?) after which you fetch your data, if no data found in store

```
this.timer$.subscribe( (..) => {
    this.fetchData();
});

this.data$.subscribe( (..) => {
    this.unsubscribeTimer();
    this.handleData();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I often do the load where I call the selector:

```
this.products$ = this.store.select(getProducts).pipe(
  tap(x => {
    if (x.length === 0) {
      this.store.dispatch(ProductActions.loadProducts());
    }
  }),
  // Filter out empty array so it doesn't emit to combineLatest
  filter(x => x.length > 0)
);
```

**Selector**

```
export const getProducts = createSelector(
  getProductFeatureState,
  state => state.products
);
```

You can find the full set of code here: https://github.com/DeborahK/Angular-NgRx-GettingStarted/tree/master/APM-Demo4

Comment: What does `getProducts` look like here?